# How to reset a timer and induce an event in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, timer, rxjs

Dear stackoverflow masterminds,

I'm new to Angular 2 and currently working on my first application. In short i want to show a sentence on screen with a timer. When this timer hits 0, i want it to reset and show the next sentence. I managed to create a timer with a variable i can use for an if-statement, this induces the next sentence but the timer does not start counting down again.

This is my code:

```
constructor() {
let timer = Observable.interval(1000).take(11);
timer.subscribe(t=>this.tickerFunc(t));

}
tickerFunc(tick){
    this.ticks = tick;
    this.count = 10-this.ticks;
      if (this.count == 0){
        this.NextSen(this.x,this.y);
        this.count = 10;
```

I pulled the original timer code from another post here. NextSen is an already working function which works. So i figured i wouldn't be useful to show.

I tried putting the constructor code below the last sentence, this did work but the tickerFunc kept getting called so the timer wouldn't stop. That code looked like this

```
tickerFunc(tick){
  this.ticks = tick;
  this.count = 10-this.ticks;
  for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.sentences.length; this.i++){
    if (this.count == 0){
      this.NextSen(this.x,this.y);
      this.count = 10;
      let timer = Observable.interval(1000).take(11);
      timer.subscribe(t=>this.tickerFunc(t));
    }
  }
```

I also tried a different timers, but these does not output variables i can use to induce an event. If needed i can provide these too. I understand that simply putting this.count back to 10 doesn't induce the times, but would really like to hear what does :)

I hope my explanation was clear, if there is anything else i need to specify please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to call `tickerFunc` recursively? I'm not even able to guess what this should be doing to be honest.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for commenting. Recalling tickerFunc will in fact reset the timer because it will create a whole new one, but by doing it this way it will endlessly continue recalling itself. I showed it in my post to give an example of my attempts to fix it.

Comment: So basically you want to show a sentence for 10s, then another one, then another one, etc?

Comment: HI Maxime, that is true. However, I already found a way to fix this so save yourself the trouble. I answered the question myself but am not able to accept the answer yet.

Comment: Even tho your solution is working, there are better "rx" way of doing that. Don't have the time right now but I can come up with a solution a bit later if you're interested

Comment: Hi Maxime, if you are willing in the future i would be very interested. I appreciate every lesson in programming :). But only if you have the time of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using this code:

```
this.countDown = Observable
  .timer(0, 1000)
  .map(tick => {
      if (10 - (tick % 11) == 0) {
        this.nextSentence();
      }
      return 10 - (tick % 11);
    }
  );
```

Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will write in console "Time reset" after every 10 second. You can configure the timing according to your need. Hope this will help you

---

ngOnInit() {

```
  var timeoutID;
  startTimer();     

  function startTimer() {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(resetTimer, 10000);        
  } 

  function resetTimer() {
    console.log('Time reset');
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);       
    startTimer();       
  }
```

}

---

Comment: Hi rakhi, thank you for commenting. The code you suggested works, but hard-coding an additional timeout does not seem like a solution to me. The problem lies in not being able to reset the initial timer without creating a recurrent loop.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while trying to do a different kind of timer reset. I think Rak2018 has the right idea, just could have explained it a bit better. I prefer this way because it can be used in javascript, I think it's more readable, and it's much easier to very the logic.

```js
var sentinces = [
  "I'm a little teapot",
  "Short and stout",
  "Here is my handle",
  "Here is my spout",
  "When I get all steamed up",
  "Hear me shout",
  "Tip me over and pour me out!"
];

var timer; //: NodeJS.Timer;

function next(index) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  if (!index) {
    index = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = sentinces[index]
  if (index + 1 < sentinces.length) {
    timer = setTimeout(() => next(index + 1), 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Press Start</div>
<button onClick="next()">Start</button>
```